# Data in bar mark not depicted accurately in Vega-Lite visual and flipping stacked bars

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

The data in my Vega-Lite visual is not being depicted accurately. Visually, the total of my target mark is higher than the total of the Usage PY mark:

[image: main image]

Looking at the data, the correct numbers are show:

[image: date]

Usage PY for Month Nr 1 sums to 78.56 whilst the target sums to 73.42, yet the orange bar is higher than the blue bar for same month (Oct). This appears to be consistent across all the months...

Why would this be?

Here's my specification:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": { 
    "values":
    [
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 1,
    "Financial Month": "Oct",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": 21.68,
    "Usage PY": 23.42,
    "Target": 21.89,
    "Production CY": 4768196,
    "Production PY": 5145233
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 1,
    "Financial Month": "Oct",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": 101.07,
    "Usage PY": 55.14,
    "Target": 51.53,
    "Production CY": 4768196,
    "Production PY": 5145233
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 2,
    "Financial Month": "Nov",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": 20.14,
    "Usage PY": 27.57,
    "Target": 25.77,
    "Production CY": 5425327,
    "Production PY": 5044930
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 2,
    "Financial Month": "Nov",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": 82.12,
    "Usage PY": 67.23,
    "Target": 62.83,
    "Production CY": 5425327,
    "Production PY": 5044930
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 3,
    "Financial Month": "Dec",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": 45.15,
    "Usage PY": 44.36,
    "Target": 41.45,
    "Production CY": 4612380,
    "Production PY": 3746604
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 3,
    "Financial Month": "Dec",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": 108.51,
    "Usage PY": 93.61,
    "Target": 87.48,
    "Production CY": 4612380,
    "Production PY": 3746604
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 4,
    "Financial Month": "Jan",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": 39.93,
    "Usage PY": 58.3,
    "Target": 54.48,
    "Production CY": 3190793,
    "Production PY": 2938725
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 4,
    "Financial Month": "Jan",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": 97.38,
    "Usage PY": 111.09,
    "Target": 103.81,
    "Production CY": 3190793,
    "Production PY": 2938725
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 5,
    "Financial Month": "Feb",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": 31.19,
    "Usage PY": 41.06,
    "Target": 38.37,
    "Production CY": 3768347,
    "Production PY": 3175390
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 5,
    "Financial Month": "Feb",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": 103.53,
    "Usage PY": 115.71,
    "Target": 108.13,
    "Production CY": 3768347,
    "Production PY": 3175390
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 6,
    "Financial Month": "Mar",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 24.33,
    "Target": 22.73,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 4686034
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 6,
    "Financial Month": "Mar",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 99.38,
    "Target": 92.87,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 4686034
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 7,
    "Financial Month": "Apr",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 28.84,
    "Target": 26.95,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2916675
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 7,
    "Financial Month": "Apr",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 159.67,
    "Target": 149.21,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2916675
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 8,
    "Financial Month": "May",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 149.29,
    "Target": 139.51,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2436180
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 8,
    "Financial Month": "May",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 22.58,
    "Target": 21.1,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2436180
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 9,
    "Financial Month": "Jun",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 16.31,
    "Target": 15.24,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 3307022
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 9,
    "Financial Month": "Jun",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 114.53,
    "Target": 107.02,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 3307022
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 10,
    "Financial Month": "Jul",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 136.08,
    "Target": 127.17,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2783133
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 10,
    "Financial Month": "Jul",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 17.78,
    "Target": 16.61,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 2783133
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 11,
    "Financial Month": "Aug",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 21.4,
    "Target": 20,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 3485137
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 11,
    "Financial Month": "Aug",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 128.52,
    "Target": 120.1,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 3485137
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 12,
    "Financial Month": "Sep",
    "KPI Name": "Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 2,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 15.86,
    "Target": 14.82,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": 4529008
  },
  {
    "Site": 7,
    "Fin Year": 2023,
    "Financial Month Nr": 12,
    "Financial Month": "Sep",
    "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
    "KPI Sort": 1,
    "Usage CY": "",
    "Usage PY": 99.09,
    "Target": 92.6,
    "Production CY": "",
    "Production PY": ""
  }
]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "'Production Current FY'",
      "as": "Production CY Legend"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "'Production Prior FY'",
      "as": "Production PY Legend"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "'Electricity Target'",
      "as": "Target Legend"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' PY'",
      "as": "CategoryPY"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' CY'",
      "as": "CategoryCY"
    }
  ],
  "height":300,
  "width":600,
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "Electricity CY",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "xOffset": 0,
        "size": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Financial Month Nr",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Usage CY",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "CategoryCY",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "Renewables PY",
              "Non-Renewables PY",
              "Renewables CY",
              "Non-Renewables CY"
            ],
            "range": [
              "#4496BC",
              "#5AC8FA",
              "#39A34B",
              "#4CD964"
            ] 
          },"legend": {"title": ""}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Electricity PY",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "xOffset": -11,
        "size": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Financial Month Nr",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Usage PY",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "CategoryPY",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "Renewables PY",
              "Non-Renewables PY",
              "Renewables CY",
              "Non-Renewables CY"
            ],
            "range": [
              "#4496BC",
              "#5AC8FA",
              "#39A34B",
              "#4CD964"
            ],
          "legend": {"title": ""}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "TARGET",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "xOffset": 11,
        "size": 10,
        "color": "orange"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Financial Month Nr",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "Target",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null
        },
        "fill": {
          "field": "Target Legend",
          "scale": {
            "range": ["orange"]
          },
          "legend": {"title": ""}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Production CY",
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Financial Month Nr",
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "Production CY",
          "type": "quantitative",
           "title": "Production (ton)"
        },
        "stroke": {
          "field": "Production CY Legend",
          "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
          "legend": {"title": ""}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Production PY",
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Financial Month Nr",
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "Production PY",
          "type": "quantitative",
           "axis": null
        },
        "stroke": {
          "field": "Production PY Legend",
          "scale": {"range": ["Blue"]},
          "legend": {"title": ""}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {"y": "independent"}
  }
}
```

Also, how can I invert both the stacked bars so that (for PY and CY) Renewables appear on top?

[vega-lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMoi0AdiUAxGrIAEATThIATmgBMABg8BmG3ZIslA0OvYAsnL09gBy7qgAjAGyQSFhkbL0aCAA8lCYiiAA0gAKAJKxSAhw2QBKcLJwAO5ITIL6haUVJmyuBageSgCqEEhkcPYAwo6eCZQAbAAcw6Pj9iUzA76UACyDIAAqbuP9HnOLAJxKJa5sygz57A7TaDsWSwkX89e3949y602YgSOzEfl8AF8FKZzKgrCBbA5nG5PD5-AjAsFQoIIlEYLF4kkMSksek8dk8gUlF1KtVsjE5Px6o0Wm0OtTyvYen00ESRmMJi9El45l54fy1hs0GIJCClEdXCdpXMxOibncHpgnlNNm8Pl8fhr-g4pahgaDwVCYZganDkk4XPFvH5kqlsbjMvi4p5XaScRksugGcROpyYlVbSBmc1Wu0DBzur1TisBTrUZQ5SAJRNTR4LJQxPCFUqBhILPD1X8tQChWI9qq84aq9rTWIvDsdhdfF4rSAzDbLPbkU60b60v68QSfcS3WTPfS2CGE7TIwzZEyGjG2fHipzuf0+atBZtFh4M-ts4C0PN8y7Dsc4P15mfFmrfprtbX675GyBKx+AVbdtO27Xt+1teFEQdFEBlHGc-Q9aJvVQdFEVnCd53QAAROAoFDCpwzpdBo1ZON8K5JNp0vIVQQzMQU0lXUdkoXxvnvRVH1eOZQSbADnl1eYEj8RYvF440rxQiwdnmeZ2zA2FILsaCRzvNCEIDL14lQzFx0QmBshwvDl0I1dGRI2N2V3RMeUSBjj15LxFgLQ9U1NLsFiJYtONQRZ8x2ZY-3fcSaME4TRMCo1qxNTZfCkmS5OhPsFKHR1UVUnT3Q0qdUB2MdMvJdAACkgnIky6k3UjLJpfcqKPNMUIuSguzsiSxCc9EvP6OtdgC-9gpiz4xWaiLm0AzYPC7XyPDEeSBztYllLS7SSV0rLkNy+DVoKkBivkYyIwXddzO3ciatsrM6qFC5818ALL1NBJHsoLwrnYksEi8bZFiJPqovq3xBosYbfpbcbJosabZoglKYOdZb0L07L6M2-LMIROAmFKg7iIqiyd2qyiBhaoUAYzV77t1UU2M6tBbpYisgr+kn3lfN4xL+00AYsVULh7RLwMHBbhyWvK5yQ+JkbUra0esDGsaIkA1w3Fk8dOwmXLWIUPu2VUWoehIy08h8D0cjM30iz8YpZ3w2ZGviJK5nm+etaGhdS2D0pW1HxevUWMMDEBwhRfaFeOsjlzOi9Ls2EBCgpzxmN8Drjc8M8LHN0b+OyQoQbG14llkm2ocFqDhY9+H1MnZC2Kl739PQIP3BD0yjtxk6I-V4mY7juq3Ma275RT1ALhfBmLZrbv2dB-PFkLnZi-m0v3bhv3EeQxSvbF+uQAAQRwJurJXcqVfbw-I677O9fGpzFg2mmBnmJrkdzrP0Bzxnp4GC4Ehk7mF43xa5dV5rXiBvBGGlsh7wPjSMqQYzJt3DmfTuF1UxCljlfXkYhGo3kHhxA8nZKBnCnhPS+dtxK5m-r-Ga-Nkpu1hnBWuW9soBUYf7beQcACe8sW7Ky3IggmNkNb2TfhgxIBCJq4Per4RqwJiGv3QWQjm40disQSCJf+MMVIV2lj7HywDtqcO4cfPhVU9yEyjqgyeKDGKpwLAFe+ZwMxyPqgol+EkPAqMEuomhc0AFlxXijJhyFXqsL0tkQqDA9qH1gVGBBpjrLJmscIhR8dEiPwBpI7yBtCEbTcWg9+49oq027BYHwHgNF0K0foz02UQkZS3uEyJRi4GtxPvwsxgiL4iKSRJR6zFdZvSyWKZ6+w8lWLcZzEpZSKlL3oZ7cBVdCThVCRAoqDBBDNMVvAtp8SKKdJ6fk0RCRWLPXsUPIS+YEhj0zi4gpNzcwWFfMcyEPjXazKqYEth2UPrVIDhEjZzdjGVXxh0xJ1ErGpKuZQR5mSDyP0Es4w5ijP55ieUnGZSl-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-ekTvG2H2fs7EmFhL4OwQCFqUO0T9HnVOlcjNOiEmPEpicjBVqTMnDsgAU8phzvnsiaYPrp-Thn+j8HxSAEz5mHJWeCLZmLTntOjdc+NzzYaQEZay+gfzy2X0hbCyACLUWYtlYS0oJLoAxtpfjkoMn6Bcv5boGoGgxXRehbQLIdZggi1DZG8l7naXJu0cwzMFXc3sgLaWykILq2ysba2zt1Az2LtnZjWKvGhOLszeO5a2792gjjF229zs8wvs-b+wDoHIOLhg52BDpQb3oew-h4jg9KPi1o7zZjrHoAcdvp3rUAA4heg4hRidOdVyACnhQqcGayUSRnFnwom-iCAXo4eags5swF9nDnOdm9S9kLzU5beC9764YfOgB1i6c5LwQ0XYu2llyAeXSGyBkE7RQM9EBgOFEV2+lOM-Izq8yJrorNRddDoN4II3SgXPP65xP9A77x3I5W7O9bIAD2Eenuc+-e8ORaSOk69eBeb8RevYpew6K6M2depOdu6AwgjQA21mbO9moAY+Cu5uk+fOiyAufm8+y2iWTmYw++fAR+J+r+hBiBhSl2s2s+1+BWWuOu+emAZWu6zW3Wsg-WRaEAJabAimABZ+TBNy0wH6UBSgLuABQBT2jeC6UAymCOEuue0BPB6OcB2O2MfBPuKBqmaBEudgA+Sg2Bw+uBjm4+POnya8B8DewuTuA2O+1BB+-6DO9BzmjBhhNurBV+eWN+hW2u9+wWeuqAT+L+DOoh4hH+9h6qshX68h-+TmShu2H2ugNQGhkBX6pOMBsccBd2gB+gbAggxWDmChTmSWIAdgygZqk6XaGOEIQAA)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the compiled Vega, you're using different scales for the bars which is why they're different heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following look right?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 21.68,
        "Usage PY": 23.42,
        "Target": 21.89,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 101.07,
        "Usage PY": 55.14,
        "Target": 51.53,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 20.14,
        "Usage PY": 27.57,
        "Target": 25.77,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 82.12,
        "Usage PY": 67.23,
        "Target": 62.83,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 45.15,
        "Usage PY": 44.36,
        "Target": 41.45,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 108.51,
        "Usage PY": 93.61,
        "Target": 87.48,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 39.93,
        "Usage PY": 58.3,
        "Target": 54.48,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 97.38,
        "Usage PY": 111.09,
        "Target": 103.81,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 31.19,
        "Usage PY": 41.06,
        "Target": 38.37,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 103.53,
        "Usage PY": 115.71,
        "Target": 108.13,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 24.33,
        "Target": 22.73,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.38,
        "Target": 92.87,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 28.84,
        "Target": 26.95,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 159.67,
        "Target": 149.21,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 149.29,
        "Target": 139.51,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 22.58,
        "Target": 21.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 16.31,
        "Target": 15.24,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 114.53,
        "Target": 107.02,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 136.08,
        "Target": 127.17,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 17.78,
        "Target": 16.61,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 21.4,
        "Target": 20,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 128.52,
        "Target": 120.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 15.86,
        "Target": 14.82,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4529008
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.09,
        "Target": 92.6,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' PY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' CY'", "as": "CategoryCY"}
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 600,
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 10},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables PY",
                  "Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Renewables CY",
                  "Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -11, "size": 10},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Renewables PY",
                  "Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Renewables CY",
                  "Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"],
                "legend": {"title": ""}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 11, "size": 10, "color": "orange"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["orange"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"},"axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Production CY",
          "mark": {"type": "line"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Production (ton)"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production CY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production PY",
          "mark": {"type": "line"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production PY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["Blue"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you sir, are a real asset to this community, you've helped my greatly in building out this unorthodox chart! THANK YOU!